# Having issue with paging in Asp.net Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using the following code:

```
  MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers(page, pageSize, out totalRecords);
        if (users != null)
        { //DO STUFF}
```

The issue is i am not getting the expected results because for the give value:

```
Page=2
pageSize=3
```

I only see 2 records to use even though the `totalrecord=8` .

Please see attached image for better understanding:

[image]

In above you can clearly see the issue ....

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1acb34(v=vs.110).aspx) carefully. This overload is useful if you only want to show part of the users, for example in a `GridView` with `Paging`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload.

```
public static MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize,
    out int totalRecords
);
```

With this overload, you are querying the users on Page 3 with PageSize 3. It will return you only two users. ie, users 7 and 8.

Try using,

public static MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers();

If you wanna implement custom paging on users see this MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya(v=vs.110).aspx#exampleToggle